# Scala implicit class restriction

Tags: scala, language-design

Scala [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) states that implicit class "must be defined inside of another trait/class/object"

What is the reason for this constraint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [referenced SIP](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/implicit-classes.html) describes implicit classes as being syntactic sugar for a `class` and a `def`.

> Annotations on implicit classes default to attaching to the generated
>   class and the method. For example,
>
> ```
> @bar
> implicit class Foo(n: Int)
> ```
>
> will desugar into:
>
> ```
> @bar implicit def Foo(n: Int): Foo = new Foo(n)
> @bar class Foo(n:Int)
> ```

**Since a `def` must be within a trait/class/object, an implicit class, being partially "composed of" a `def`, must also obey this condition.**

Comment: It make sense, but why they don't just put `def Foo(n: Int)` into `Foo` class?

Comment: @talex : think about how you would have to call the `def` then. You need a stable path to an implicit conversion in order to use it. You see the problem?

Comment: You mean I well nee to have instance of `Foo` to call it. But it won't be used explicitly so it can be transformed directly to java static method.

Comment: @tale : yeah, you would need to first create a "dummy" instance of the `Foo` class, bind it to a stable path (e.g. by assigning to a `val`) and make it accessible to your code (e.g. by importing the `def` from that instance). I'm not sure what you mean with the "transformation to a static method" though?

Comment: The reason that `def Foo` requires outer class is obviously that JVM work that way. So creators of Scala was in need of container where to put this `def`. I suggest to use `Foo` class (because it exists anyway) instead of introducing new one with a single purpose to put this `def` into it.